# Reactjs - antd table filter as a react class

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to create an antd table as a react class instead of a component, although I am running into syntax errors.

```
  Line 170:  'state' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 179:  'onInputChange' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 183:  'onSearch' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 232:  'renderTable' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 283:  'renderTable' is not defined    no-undef
```

I am trying to import the "custom filter panel" demo 
https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel

Do I need to place things into a constructor on this class? Use a different function notation instead of the arrows?

```js
var ProfileUserTable = React.createClass({
    render: function () {

      state = {
        filterDropdownVisible: false,
        data,
        searchText: '',
        filtered: false,
      };

      

      onInputChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ searchText: e.target.value });
      }

      onSearch = () => {
        const { searchText } = this.state;
        const reg = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
        this.setState({
          filterDropdownVisible: false,
          filtered: !!searchText,
          data: data.map((record) => {
            const match = record.name.match(reg);
            if (!match) {
              return null;
            }
            return {
              ...record,
              name: (
                <span>
                  {record.name.split(reg).map((text, i) => (
                    i > 0 ? [<span className="highlight">{match[0]}</span>, text] : text
                  ))}
                </span>
              ),
            };
          }).filter(record => !!record),
        });
      }


      const data = [{
        key: '1',
        name: 'John Brown',
        age: 32,
        address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
      }, {
        key: '2',
        name: 'Joe Black',
        age: 42,
        address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
      }, {
        key: '3',
        name: 'Jim Green',
        age: 32,
        address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
      }, {
        key: '4',
        name: 'Jim Red',
        age: 32,
        address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
      }];


      renderTable = () => {
         const columns = [{
              title: 'Name',
              dataIndex: 'name',
              key: 'name',
              filterDropdown: (
                <div className="custom-filter-dropdown">
                  <Input
                    ref={ele => this.searchInput = ele}
                    placeholder="Search name"
                    value={this.state.searchText}
                    onChange={this.onInputChange}
                    onPressEnter={this.onSearch}
                  />
                  <Button type="primary" onClick={this.onSearch}>Search</Button>
                </div>
              ),
              filterIcon: <Icon type="smile-o" style={{ color: this.state.filtered ? '#108ee9' : '#aaa' }} />,
              filterDropdownVisible: this.state.filterDropdownVisible,
              onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
                this.setState({
                  filterDropdownVisible: visible,
                }, () => this.searchInput.focus());
              },
            }, {
              title: 'Age',
              dataIndex: 'age',
              key: 'age',
            }, {
              title: 'Address',
              dataIndex: 'address',
              key: 'address',
              filters: [{
                text: 'London',
                value: 'London',
              }, {
                text: 'New York',
                value: 'New York',
              }],
              onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.indexOf(value) === 0,
            }];
            
            return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />;
                
      } 


      return (
        <div className="component-container">
          
            {renderTable()}    

        </div>
      );
    }
});



ReactDOM.render(<ProfileUserTable/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing many things.

The demo uses ES6 React classes with arrow functions so you will need babel and [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin or stage-2

To make it work with React.createClass you will need to convert the demo code into proper createClass style with ES5. eg:

`Line 170:  'state' is not defined          no-undef`

Means you haven't properly set the `state` also the state object should not go inside of render, it should got to `getInitialState()`

`Line 179:  'onInputChange' is not defined  no-undef`

the function onInputChange is declared with arrow functions, you should convert to normal js function.

eg.

```
var SayHello = createReactClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {message: 'Hello!'};
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    alert(this.state.message);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Say hello
      </button>
    );
  }
});
```

This question is more about React with es5 vs es6 I would suggest you read their differences:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html

https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/#state-differences

Last, [createClass is deprecated](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html)

Comment: I've managed to get it fixed -- but how do I clean this up to fetch the data from a parent -- so this.props.data --- and also push it into the onSearch -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/189/  - @Kossel

Comment: Well this can be another completely different topic. but usually people would setup Redux (or any other flux lib), and map the search function and the result data from the store to the props. so you  would use real data.

Comment: - sure - I got redux working -- I've got it setup now -- so its closer to getting it working as a standalone component